# App occasionally shows old close reasons

Tags: bug, android-app, api

Occasionally when voting to close a question in the Android app, I'm presented with the old close reasons ("to broad" instead of "needs more focus" for example).

It seems to display one set for awhile, then switches over to the other set. I don't *think* it's caching related since it switches back and forth. I can't figure out a pattern; it seems to be random.

And yes, I know the app isn't going to be fixed. This is potentially a problem with the API though, so I thought I'd mention it.